# Im getting TypeError using req, res

Tags: node.js

I'm getting TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'content-type')

This is my code:

```
const express = require("express");
const res = require("express/lib/response");
const app = express()

app.get('/cats', (req, res) => {
res.send('meow!')
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
res.send('MEOW!!')
})
```

Comment: remove the line `const res = require("express/lib/response");`

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code run with two changes.  Remove this line `const res = require("express/lib/response");` and change the second `res.send('MEOW!!')` to `console.log('MEOW!!')`.

Change this:

```
const express = require("express");
const res = require("express/lib/response");
const app = express()

app.get('/cats', (req, res) => {
    res.send('meow!')
})

app.listen(8080, () => {
    res.send('MEOW!!')
})
```

to this:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get('/cats', (req, res) => {
    res.send('meow!');
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
   console.log('MEOW!!');
});
```